# What is the best way to loop through a collection of records and pass back an object to the front end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that returns user reports, and one of the methods sums up the points of said reports, per user. I want to pass back an object of this data to the front end so it can be displayed. Ideally my object would be shaped like this:

```
data: {
  users: {
    $user_id: {
      name: "Foo Bar",
      points: 100
    },
    $user_id: {
      name: "Foo Bar Two",
      points: 10
    }
  }
}
```

However my current implementation is not building the object like this, and simply adding to one big object.

My code looks like this:

```
  def user_points
    hash = {}
    User.all.each do |u|
      user_points = Report.select("points").where("user_id = ?", u.id).sum("points")
      hash.merge!(
        user: 
        {
          first_name: u.first_name,
          last_name:u.last_name,
          time_zone: u.time_zone
        }
      )
    end
    render json: { data: hash }
  end
```

and the resulting object only included the last user in one big object

```
data:
  user:
  first_name: "Test"
  last_name: "Test"
  points: 200
  time_zone: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

Comment: The merge keeps updating the user key.  Need to change `user` to something like u.id.to_sym so you have a unique key for each entry.

Comment: Don't use the same test values for first_name & last_name. It does not verify that the assignments were made correctly.

Comment: Why did you use in your "ideal" object `name` and `points` but in the code `first_name`, `last_name` and `time_zone`. What structure do you want?

Comment: Out of the question but I would suggest to **never** use `User.all`. What if you've 2M users?  Prefer [find_each](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieve the same result by joining both the table and then performing aggregation on joined table.

```sql
select users.id, users.name, sum(reports.points) as points from users join reports on users.id = reports.user_id group by users.id;
```

[sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc0973/1/0)

Thank you max for the comment.

```rb
def user_points
  result = User.join(:reports)
            .select(
              :first_name,
              :last_name,
              Report.arel_table[:points].sum.as(:points),
              :time_zone
            )
            .group(:id)
  render json: { data: result }
end
```

**Output:**

```
data:
  first_name: "Test1"
  last_name: "Test1"
  points: 100

  first_name: "Test2"
  last_name: "Test2"
  points: 200

  first_name: "Test3"
  last_name: "Test3"
  points: 300
```

Comment: Instead of a long SQL string you can use `.select(:first_name, :last_name, 
Report.arel_table[:points].sum.as(:points), :time_zone)`. ActiveRecord will prefix the column names with "this" table. You can use just use `.group(:id)` instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by dbugger you need to provide a unique key for each hash entry otherwise merge will just replace an existing value.

For example:

```
{a: :foo}.merge(b: :bar)
=> {:a=>:foo, :b=>:bar}
```

and

```
{a: :foo}.merge(b: :bar).merge(a: :foo_bar)
{:a=>:foo_bar, :b=>:bar}
```

You might want to consider returning a json array rather than an object with unique property names.

maybe something like this?

```
  def user_points
    result = User.all.map do |u|
      points = Report.select("points").where("user_id = ?", u.id).sum("points")
        {
          first_name: u.first_name,
          last_name:u.last_name,
          time_zone: u.time_zone
          points: points
        }
    end
    render json: { data: result }
  end
```